# Compile shader and root signature of a ray tracing shader into a single binary using DXC

Tags: directx, raytracing, directx12

I'm new to DXR, so please

If I got it right, when we want to compile a ray tracing shader using the [DirectX Shader Compiler](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXShaderCompiler), we need to specify `lib_6_*` as the target profile.

Now assume I've got a HLSL file containing a single ray generation shader `RayGen` whose root signature is specified by a RootSignature attribute of the form

```
#define MyRS "RootFlags(LOCAL_ROOT_SIGNATURE),"  \
        "DescriptorTable("                  \
            "UAV(u0, numDescriptors = 1),"  \
            "SRV(t0, numDescriptors = 1))"
[rootsignature(MyRS)]
[shader("raygeneration")] 
void RayGen() {}
```

Using `IDxcCompiler::Compile`, I'm able to compile both the shader itself using the target profile `lib_6_3` and the root signature using the target profile `rootsig_1_1`, but if I got it right it's not possible to invoke `IDxcCompiler::Compile` such that the created `IDxcBlob` contains both the shader and the root signature. (I've tried to add the argument `-rootsig-define MyRS` to the call for the compilation of the shader, but it seems to me that the compiler expects the root signature specified in this way to be a *global* root signature.)

So, I end up with two `IDxcBlob`'s. Is there any possibility to "merge" them into a single one which can later be used to specify the shader as well in a call of `ID3D12Device5::CreateRootSignature`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ID3D12Device::CreateRootSignature` expects a pointer to the data, as well as the data length. You could combine your shader and root signature into one blob, but you'd need to know the offset from the start of the file to your signature (or if the signature were first, then when you create a shader you would need to know the offset from the start of the file to the compiled DXIL).

You could create a file that looked like this:

```
FileIdentifier
OffsetToShader
ShaderLength
OffsetToSignature
SignatureLength
ShaderData
...
...
...
SignatureData
...
...
...
```

Then when you load your custom file, you would have all of the data and data lengths at your disposal.

To write an `IDxcBlob`, you can access the raw data and size via it's functions:

```
struct IDxcBlob : public IUnknown {
public:
  virtual LPVOID STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetBufferPointer(void) = 0;
  virtual SIZE_T STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetBufferSize(void) = 0;
};
```

Then just write the data to a file with something like `fwrite`:

```
fwrite(blob->GetBufferPointer(), 1, blob->GetBufferSize(), fileHandle);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How would I actually combine/concatenate two blobs into a single one?

Comment: @0xbadf00d, I've updated the answer to show how to access the blob data.

Comment: Thank you for your update. What I've actually meant is whether there is a utility in the API allowing me to merge two blobs. However, meanwhile I've seen that there is [another way to specify a root signature in HLSL](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3dhlsl/dx-graphics-hlsl-state-object). The only problem is that when I'm trying to use this and compile the code with target profile "lib_6_3" I'm receiving the following compiler error: "The module cannot be validated by the version of the validator currently attached." I wasn't able to find anything on google.

Comment: Do you know what the cause of this is?

Comment: There's no API to merge blobs, as it's just a simple operation that can be achieved manually. I don't know anything about the error message, perhaps try a new question.

Comment: Couldn't we use the `IDxcContainerBuilder` and `AddPart` to add the local root signature to the shader library?